# Map key to copy to next window

Tags: key-bindings

Say I have two windows open, and I would like to copy lines from the first window to the second window, and then move back the original window. I do this as follows:

```
<select lines in Visual mode>
y
Ctrl+w
w
p
Ctrl+w
w
```

I would like to map this to a key.  My attempt is the following:

```
:map <F2> y :wincmd j<CR> p
```

It successfully copies the lines from one window to the other, but I can't seem to successfully make it jump back up to the previous window.  How can I add this next part?  The following does not work:

```
:map <F2> y :wincmd j<CR> p <ESC> :wincmd k<CR>
```

Comment: How did you manage to miss `<C-w>p` and `:wincmd p` when you read `:help window-move-cursor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are in visual mode when you press <kbd>F2</kbd>, you need to map this key in visual mode, so you need to substitute `:map` for `:vmap`. But be careful with spaces because they move the cursor to the right in normal mode (see [`:help l`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#l)). Here you go.

```
:vmap <F2> y:wincmd j<CR>p:wincmd k<CR>
```